# Expected primary expression before "<<" token С++

Tags: c++

Пишет Expected primary expression before "<<" token 4 раза, не знаю что делать. Да, не обращайте внимания на дебилизм который тут написан, я начинающий программист - аутист.
p.s. Код в этом посте тоже упоротый - частично работает, частично пишется в строчку... My fault, не суть.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUSSIAN")

;int a;

cout << ("Здравствуй, Пользователь."); << endl;
cout << ("Нажмите цифру от 1 до 5 чтобы поприветствоваться или любую другую             чтобы отклонить"); << endl;
if ( a <= 5) // если a меньше или равно 5, то
{

cout << ("У меня для тебя важное задание. Ты готов принять его?"); << endl;
cout << ("Нажмите цифру от 1 до 5 чтобы согласиться или любую другую чтобы  отклонить"); << endl;
if ( a <= 5) // если a меньше или равно 5, то
{
cout << ("Твоя судьба в твоих руках. Ты должен взломать Пентагон") << endl;
cout << ("Нажми цифру от 1 до 5 чтобы взломать Пентагон или любую другую     чтобы отклонить") << endl;
if ( a <= 5) // если a меньше или равно 5, то
{
for (int counter = 0; counter < 1000; counter++)
cout << ("Молодец") << endl;
cout << ("YOU WIN") << endl;
}   else // иначе
cout << ("Мда, ты всё запорол.") << endl;
cout << ("GAME OVER") << endl;

} else // иначе
{

cout << ("Ты подвел меня.") << endl;
cout << ("GAME OVER") << endl;
}

} else // иначе
{
cout << ("Я наделся на тебя. Прощай.") << endl;
cout << ("GAME OVER") << endl;
}

cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << ("Здравствуй, Пользователь."); << endl;
```

Тут не надо точку с запятой. Надо так:

```
cout << ("Здравствуй, Пользователь.") << endl;
```

Comment: Убрал. Все почти до конца компилируется и выдает id returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 2):

Помимо того, что в некоторых предложениях, как в этом

```
cout << ("Здравствуй, Пользователь."); << endl;
                                    ^^^
```

вы поставили точку с запятой, что делает эти предложения синтаксически неверными, вы также нигде не вводите значение в переменную `a`

```
;int a;
```

Поэтому эта переменная имеет неопределенное значение.

Я думаю вы имели в виду использовать по крайней  мере одно предложение

```
cin >> a;
```

перед многочисленными if-предложениями.

Желательно также правильно форматировать текст программы. Это помогает увидеть логические ошибки. Ваши вложенные if-else предложения выглядят следующим образом:

```
if ( a <= 5)
{
    if ( a <= 5)
    {
        if ( a <= 5)
        {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < 1000; counter++)
                cout << ("Молодец") << endl;
            cout << ("YOU WIN") << endl;
        }   
        else
            cout << ("Мда, ты всё запорол.") << endl;
        cout << ("GAME OVER") << endl;

    } 
    else
    {
        cout << ("Ты подвел меня.") << endl;
        cout << ("GAME OVER") << endl;
    }
} 
else // иначе
{
    cout << ("Я наделся на тебя. Прощай.") << endl;
    cout << ("GAME OVER") << endl;
}
```

Comment: @CTS_12345 В каком плане? Исправлять ошибки в программе и дальше работать над ней.:)

Comment: Я исправил целый ряд ошибок, используя все ответы, данные мне здесь. Теперь осталась лишь одна ошибка id returned 1 exit status.

Comment: @CTS_12345 Покажите полное сообщение об ошибке с номером предложения. Иначе не ясно, что это за ошибка.

Comment: Это странно, но никакой дополнительной информации программа не даёт. Просто пишет название проблемы и всё:
Строка: - ; Файл: -; Сообщение: id returned 1 exit status

Comment: @CTS_12345 Если указанные ошибки исправили, то программа должна компилироваться и выполняться.. Это может быть какое-то несущественное предупреждение. Я не знаю, о чем она предупреждает. Поставьте на всякий случай в конце программы return 0; хотя это не принципиально.

Comment: Поставил, ошибка исчезла, теперь это...

6 C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\Projects\FIRSTPROJECT.cpp:52 expected unqualified-id before 'return'

Comment: @CTS_12345 В самом конце программы перед закрывающейся фигурной скобкой вставьте return 0; Все. Больше ничего от себя добавлять не надо.

Comment: В общем ладно, тут уже самому надо разбираться, видимо пропустил я всё же какую-то ошибку. Спасибо за помощь)